# Error occurred when i use Link component of react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I developed a simple admin dashboard and I use latest version of React router dom. I have a sidebar with some links. But when I use `<Link>` component of React router dom I got error and the app crashes. All routes is in a file called router.jsx, my sidebar and the App which has `<RouterProvider />`. Can you help me to solve this error.

Routes.js:

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Users from "./Pages/Users/Users";
import ProductsList from "./Pages/Products/ProductsList";
import Orders from "./Pages/Orders/Orders";
import Reviews from "./Pages/Reviews/Reviews";

const Routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Dashboard />,
  },
  {
    path: "/users",
    element: <Users />,
  },
  {
    path: "/products",
    element: <ProductsList />,
  },
  {
    path: "/orders",
    element: <Orders />,
  },
  {
    path: "/reviews",
    element: <Reviews />,
  },
]);

export default Routes;
```

App.jsx:

```
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import NavBar from "./Components/Nav Bar/NavBar";
import FooterCopyRight from "./Components/Footer/FooterCopyRight";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-12 bg-gray-100 min-h-screen">
      <div className="bg-white p-5 col-span-2 hidden lg:flex border-x-2 shadow">
        <Sidebar />
      </div>

      <div className="p-5 col-span-10 bg-gray-100 min-h-screen">
        <NavBar />
        <RouterProvider router={Routes} />

        <FooterCopyRight />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And I use Link Component like this:

```
 <li className={liStyles}>
     <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
</li>
```

I just wanted to have a separate file for all routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use children on the root url like:

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Users from "./Pages/Users/Users";
import ProductsList from "./Pages/Products/ProductsList";
import Orders from "./Pages/Orders/Orders";
import Reviews from "./Pages/Reviews/Reviews";

const Routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Base />,
    children: [
        {
            path: "",
            element: <Dashboard />,
        },
        {
            path: "/users",
            element: <Users />,
        },
        {
            path: "/products",
            element: <ProductsList />,
        },
        {
            path: "/orders",
            element: <Orders />,
        },
        {
            path: "/reviews",
            element: <Reviews />,
        },
    ]
  },
  
]);

export default Routes;
```

then create the Base component :

```
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import NavBar from "./Components/Nav Bar/NavBar";
import FooterCopyRight from "./Components/Footer/FooterCopyRight";

function Base() {
  return (
    <div className="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-12 bg-gray-100 min-h-screen">
      <div className="bg-white p-5 col-span-2 hidden lg:flex border-x-2 shadow">
        <Sidebar />
      </div>

      <div className="p-5 col-span-10 bg-gray-100 min-h-screen">
        <NavBar />
        <Outlet />

        <FooterCopyRight />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Base;
```

and finally update App component:

```
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./Routes";


function App() {
  return (
  <RouterProvider router={Routes} />
  );
}

export default App;
```